# How to filter pandas or pyspark dataframe values in columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a dataframe with this values:

```
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|tag_html|tag_css|tag_javascript|count|
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|     0.0|    0.0|           0.0| 8655|
|     1.0|    0.0|           0.0|  141|
|     0.0|    0.0|           1.0|  782|
|     1.0|    0.0|           1.0|  107|
|     0.0|    1.0|           0.0|   96|
|     0.0|    1.0|           1.0|   20|
|     1.0|    1.0|           1.0|   46|
|     1.0|    1.0|           0.0|  153|
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
```

I want the rows where "1" is not repeated in the other columns like this

```
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|tag_html|tag_css|tag_javascript|count|
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|     1.0|    0.0|           0.0|  141|
|     0.0|    0.0|           1.0|  782|
|     0.0|    1.0|           0.0|   96|
```

what I have done is this, using the function `where()`

```
df['count'].where(((asdf['tag_html'] == 1) | (asdf['tag_css'] == 0) | (asdf['tag_javascript'] == 0)) & 
               ((asdf['tag_html'] == 0) | (asdf['tag_css'] == 1) | (asdf['tag_javascript'] == 0)) &
               ((asdf['tag_html'] == 0) | (asdf['tag_css'] == 0) | (asdf['tag_javascript'] == 1)))
```

this is the result

```
0    8655.0
1     141.0
2     782.0
3       NaN
4      96.0
5       NaN
6      46.0
7       NaN
```

Is there a better way to do this in pandas or pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `mask` and Boolean index

```
df=df.assign(count=df['count'].mask(df.iloc[:,:3].eq(1).sum(1).gt(1)))
df
Out[513]: 
   tag_html  tag_css  tag_javascript   count
0       0.0      0.0             0.0  8655.0
1       1.0      0.0             0.0   141.0
2       0.0      0.0             1.0   782.0
3       1.0      0.0             1.0     NaN
4       0.0      1.0             0.0    96.0
5       0.0      1.0             1.0     NaN
6       1.0      1.0             1.0     NaN
7       1.0      1.0             0.0     NaN
```